# Creating map function in Red language

Tags: higher-order-functions, rebol, red

How can I create [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)), a higher order function, in Red language. It should take a block and a function as arguments and apply the sent function to each member of block. I tried following code:

```
Red []
mapfn: function[blk sfn][
    outblk: copy []
    foreach i blk[
        append outblk (sfn i) ]
    outblk ]

; to test: 
myblk: [" this " " is   " " a "  "    line " "for" "   testing " " only   "]
probe mapfn myblk 'reverse 
probe mapfn myblk 'trim
```

But it is not working - it simply sends back the original block without changing it or giving any error message. How can this be corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rebol you have the mezzanine function **apply**

```
>> help apply
USAGE:
    APPLY func block /only 

DESCRIPTION:
     Apply a function to a reduced block of arguments.
     APPLY is a function value.

ARGUMENTS:
     func -- Function value to apply (Type: any-function)
     block -- Block of args, reduced first (unless /only) (Type: block)

REFINEMENTS:
     /only -- Use arg values as-is, do not reduce the block

(SPECIAL ATTRIBUTES)
     throw
```

See **source apply**.

As long as Red has no native apply you can write your own mapping function e.g

```
mapfn: function[blk sfn][
    outblk: copy []
    foreach i blk[
        append outblk sfn copy i 
    ]
    outblk 
]
```

Get the function with :functionname

```
>> myblk: [" this " " is   " " a "  "    line " "for" "   testing " " only   "]
== [" this " " is   " " a " "    line " "for" "   testing " " only   "]
>> probe mapfn myblk :reverse 
[" siht " "   si " " a " " enil    " "rof" " gnitset   " "   ylno "]
== [" siht " "   si " " a " " enil    " "rof" " gnitset   " "   ylno "]
>> probe mapfn myblk :trim
["this" "is" "a" "line" "for" "testing" "only"]
== ["this" "is" "a" "line" "for" "testing" "only"]
>>
```

An alternative and better way as you can not copy all datatypes is e.g.

```
mapfn: function[blk sfn][
    collect [
        foreach i blk[
            keep sfn i 
        ]
    ]
]
```

and call the function this way if no do not want to modify the original

```
mapfn newblk: copy/deep myblk :reverse
```

Comment: I changed the answer. **reverse** and **trim** work on the original series and change it. So you have to use a copy of the series you work on.