# What's the equivalent of Rebol apply in Red if any?

Tags: rebol, red

Rebol has apply [Creating map function in Red language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753092/creating-map-function-in-red-language) what's the equivalent of Rebol apply in Red if any ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there's no native `apply` in Red. You can write `apply` on your own:

```
apply: func [
    "Apply a function to a block of arguments"
    fn      [any-function!] "Function value to apply"
    args    [block!]        "Block of arguments (to quote refinement use QUOTE keyword)"
    /local refs vals val
][
    refs: copy []
    vals: copy []
    set-val: [set val skip (append/only vals val)]
    parse args [
        some [
            'quote set-val
        |   set val refinement! (append refs to word! val)
        |   set-val
        ]
    ]
    do compose [(make path! head insert refs 'fn) (vals)]
]
```

It works bit differently than Rebol's `apply` (because I don't like Rebol's `apply` syntax). If you define some function:

```
f: func [
    foo
    /bar
        baz
][
    reduce [foo bar baz]
]
```

then here's how to use this `apply`:

```
>> apply :f [1 /bar 1]
== [1 true 1]
>> apply :f [quote /bar]
== [/bar false none]
>> apply :f [quote /bar /bar 1]
== [/bar true 1]
```

See http://red.qyz.cz/apply-and-ufcs.html for details.